# Unable to use useSelector and useDispatch in export const function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, useselector

I am unable to use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` in export const function.

```js
export const StartTelecalling = (piopiy, userId, password) => {
  const { modal, isTestCall, isOnline } = useSelector((state) => state.calls);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  piopiy.login(userId, password, "sbcind.telecmi.com");
  console.log("login Initiated..............");
  piopiy.on("login", (object) => {
    console.log(object);
    // if (object.code === 200) {
    console.log("login successfully......");
    //   dispatch(setIsOnline(true));

    // }
  });
}
```

In the above code I am getting invalid hook call at `useSelector` and `useDispatch` and I have multiple exports like that I can't declare as default export.

Answer (score 2):

Default export or not, you are breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

> ## Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.
>
> ## Only Call Hooks from React Functions
>
> **Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.** Instead, you can:
>
> - ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> - ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks

`StartTelecalling` is neither a React component nor a custom React hook.

You can either convert `StartTelecalling` into a custom React hook, basically just rename it to use the `"use-"` hook prefix naming convention, so that it can call other React hooks:

```js
export const useStartTeleCalling = (piopiy, userId, password) => {
  const { modal, isTestCall, isOnline } = useSelector((state) => state.calls);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  return () => 
    piopiy.login(userId, password, "sbcind.telecmi.com");
    console.log("login Initiated..............");
    piopiy.on("login", (object) => {
      console.log(object);
      // if (object.code === 200) {
      console.log("login successfully......");
      //   dispatch(setIsOnline(true));

       // }
    });
  };
}
```

```js
const startTeleCalling = useStartTeleCalling(piopiy, userId, password);

...

startTeleCalling();
```

Or refactor the function to have the selected state and `dispatch` function passed in as arguments.

```js
export const startTeleCalling = ({
  piopiy,
  userId,
  password,
  modal,
  isTestCall,
  isOnline,
  dispatch
}) => {
  piopiy.login(userId, password, "sbcind.telecmi.com");
  console.log("login Initiated..............");
  piopiy.on("login", (object) => {
    console.log(object);
    // if (object.code === 200) {
    console.log("login successfully......");
    //   dispatch(setIsOnline(true));

     // }
  });
}
```

```js
const { modal, isTestCall, isOnline } = useSelector((state) => state.calls);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

...

startTeleCalling({
  piopiy,
  userId,
  password,
  modal,      // <-- pass selected state
  isTestCall, // <-- pass selected state
  isOnline,   // <-- pass selected state
  dispatch    // <-- pass dispatch
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call hooks inside nested functions, loops, conditions or regular JS functions as per React [documentation.](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) Also, React Hooks can only be called at the top level. Apparently, you are calling the hooks inside a regular JS function. Calling these hooks inside a functional react component might solve the issue.